# axios equivalent of curl -u flag

Tags: curl, axios

I am trying to implement a frontend in axios for a backend that gives frontend example in curl.  What would the axios equivalent of the following be?  I am not sure how to represent the -u flag.

```
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:9000/auth -i -u test@example.com:123456
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-u` or `--user` flag in `curl` is used to:

```
Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication.
```

Following that reasoning the property you're looking for is `auth` within `axios`, an example:

```js
axios('https://example.com', {
  auth: {
   username: 'john.doe',
   password: 'penny_lane',
  }
})
```

Here's the reference to the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

Note that axios only automatically creates the authorization headers from auth:{...} on GET requests.  If you want to generate the same header on a POST you will have to make it directly.

```
const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, 'utf8').toString('base64')

const url = 'https://...'
const data = {
  ...
}

axios.post(url, data, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`
  },
})
```